# Microsoft BranchCache vs. 3rd part WAN Accelerators?

Tags: windows-server-2008, wide-area-network

My client needs to improve the performance of their WAN. They have three sites spread som 600 km apart with roughly 400 users per site. It's mainly a Microsoft environment.

Today they are using Windows XP clients and Windows Server 2003 (and some 2008 R2)

They have done a pilot with a 3rd party WAN accelerator and performance increase was good but it did not work as transparently as they wished for.

Since this is a Microsoft shop I want to recommend them to upgrade clients to Windows 7 and servers to Windows Server 2008 R2 and enable branche cache.

But I have no experience of my own with branchecache and thus I am asking everyone here at ServerFault, what is your experience of using Microsoft BranchCache to optimize WAN performance?

Comment: It looks like BranchCache caches web and file content. Is that going to be enough? What about email, databases, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Why not also consider a branchcache pilot for some additional custom fitting and analysis?